# iis7 how to disable anon access, basic authentication, and enable windows authentication on ONE file in a website

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, windows-authentication

I have a product I'm evaluating called bugtracker.net, it has the ability to authenticate through both windows auth. and a local db with user accounts. For this to work I need to let the code handle authenticating against the db, but I also have a form that authenticates against AD. For this one file to work "loginnt.aspx", it needs to be set to use windows authorization, but I need the rest of the folder to allow anon access.

Please help I'm so close to get this to work, and the instructions were written for iis6, this ability couldn't possibly be lost in iis7???

Answer (score 0):

In IIS 7, you can target the properties of an individual file in IIS Manager by:

- Switching to Content view in the tab at the bottom
- Right-clicking the file you're wanting to edit

  - Choosing "Features View" from the context menu

At this point, you'll have a reduced list of capabilities presented to you, and you'll see the filename in the node list in the connections pane.

At the bottom of the window, the status bar should indicate that you're editing a  tag referring to the filename when you change any of the property settings.

Hopefully that gets you where you need to go...